Upcoming voting experiment to encourage people who rarely vote to upvote
We are rolling out two small voting experiments that will likely start sometime in January on Stack Overflow that we hope will increase voting engagement.
Why we are doing this
We don’t see many users who hold voting privileges participating in voting. This breaks down as follows, on a monthly average:

Only 20% of registered users who have the upvote privilege are using it.
Only 6% of registered users who have the downvoting privilege are using it.

Voting is one of the most significant actions users can take to signal quality on the network. We would like to see what minor actions we can take to encourage users to vote more frequently on content they visit. These experiments will only be visible to those with voting privileges.
New upvoting popover
We plan to prompt users who have voting privileges but have not engaged with the feature much (e.g., once every three months, never voted before, etc.). Users that fall into that group would see the prompt below. If the popover is dismissed, the user won’t see the prompt for a period of time.

Vote prompt
For Q&A that has no score or answers that have equal up and down votes the zero will be replaced with the word “vote”.

If you have any questions or feedback, please let us know. We will be monitoring feedback on this post till December 23rd, 2024.

"For Q&A that has no score or answers that have equal up and down votes the zero will be replaced with the word “vote”." Will clicking on "Vote" still display the number of up and down votes on said post?

Don't we already have this feature where a user is reminded to vote? Oh wait I think that is that only when the user only votes for answers and it tells them to vote for questions as well?

@AbdulAzizBarkat also, only really takes the last N votes. I've visited an existing old Q&A, voted on the question then went through the answers. Only for the system to scold me for not voting on questions recently.

This may also be neat for Discussions, but only when the downvoting is allowed again there.

Yes, @ThomA, users who have the privilege to will still be able to see the score breakdown.

Have you considered invoking a culture war? Seems to work well to engage the voters. And disengage others, unfortunately, but you might see a net improvement.

But you haven't actually fixed the problem that is the reason why I haven't touched the upvote button since Oct 2021.  The problem is that the vast majority of new questions are garbage.  Fix that first.

Finally. SO tell me to go and downvote. After all that years of "be nice" campaigns.

"Only 6% of registered users who have the downvoting privilege are using it." Some of those users actively don't downvote. There are many (inc very high rep) users who despite having made 10's of thousands of votes, their number of downvotes are in the 10's or 100's. This isn't because they don't know about the feature, they actively don't use it. Of course, there are users who have (many) more downvotes than upvotes (myself included), but downvotes have a "reputation" of intentionally not being used and, in my opinion, the education on them needs to me more than a reminder they exist.

Just to be clear, we actively dis-incentivize downvoting and are confused as to why people don't do it as much? I know that some feel the penalty should be increased Increase the downvote penalty for downvotee on answers from 2 to 4 but if you want to incentivize voting, perhaps curators should be rewarded for curation of content not punished.

Given that the JNat commented that this experiment will only focus on upvotes this post feels dishonest (which might not have been the intention, but is the result). The text is written in a neutral way which implies the experiment is about up- and downvotes, but in practice downvotes are ignored yet again. I guess in theory one could divine that from the fact that the screenshot only shows an "upvote this" prompt but yeah, a more honest way to communicate this would put that information front and center.

I suppose we could easily "fix" that, @l4mpi ; we correct the title to "Upcoming voting experiment to encourage people who rarely vote to upvote" and change references to the "vote prompt" to "upvote prompt".

I'm for this so long as it's not just pushing people to vote simply for the sake of "voting" and pumping numbers up. I'd prefer people understand why they are voting. Does this initiative have anything to address teaching users how and why to vote?

Don't we already have popups like this related to voting? like i'll get a "Welcome Back! Don't forget to vote!" popup when i visit a site i haven't voted on recently.. there's one that complains when i haven't voted on questions in the past n votes, there's one that pops up when you first earn the privilege to vote, i don't expect one more to have any meaningful impact... certainly not one that would put a dent in current trends.

I'll tell you why people don't downvote: (1) it costs them something, which sensibly discourages downvoting (2) the quality signal is soon "compensated" by someone who upvotes out of "let's not be mean".

Unless it is so bad that someone else also downvotes it as well, and then question is deleted and you lost nothing.

Coincidentally I got that "you haven't voted on questions in a while" prompt today, @KevinB, and I didn't even know it existed until your comment. More oddly, the last time I voted on a question was 6 hours ago (unless there's a deleted question I voted on more recently)... Apparently I need to vote on questions more than once every 6 hours? Makes me wonder if this pop-up will have other odd behaviour now.

@ThomA it's not time based, it happens when you vote on a lot of answers in a row, commonly happens when you find one of those old posts with 60 useless answers

Ahh, that'll explain it then. @KevinB , I'm at -14 reputation today . Feels flawed then that it's based on volume, rather than time...

@ChristophRackwitz "There should be no rep penalty for downvoting the answer (at least when voter has no skin in the game)..."

In case this is not already planned, the second change about replacing 0 with Vote should not apply to posts you own or are otherwise ineligible to vote on. Them being zero score should still be made clear to the post author.

Or any other post you can't vote on (ex. you already voted, its locked, etc.)

@Starship-OnDiscussionsStrike Agreed.

Honestly, there is no reason to have vote buttons at all on your own posts, or at least they should be greyed out and inactive.

@PiotrSiupa Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts

This experiment does take into consideration whether or not the user can vote on the posts.


For Q&A that has no score or answers that have equal up and down votes the zero will be replaced with the word “vote”.

This seems unnecessarily confusing. I imagine a fair few users would assume the vote count is locked, or hidden, or requires something extra (privilege, payment), or something.
Keeping the zero but having some extra notice around it to incentivise voting would probably have been clearer.
Another alternative I have seen on GOG.com is that when there are no user submitted scores for an item yet, the aggregate rating shows up as "Be first to rate":



I want to address a point that JNat made in a comment:

The experiment will focus on upvoting only; answers only; on the top answer only, if there are multiple. The pop-over will not show concurrently to the currently existing banners. We will see what we learn, and go from there.

This feels like a terrible idea to me. Upvotes and downvotes are really important, and the Question here makes it very apparent that downvotes aren't in use any where near as much as upvotes, with only 6% and 20% using their votes respectively. Downvotes are the clear loser in that scenario. This is evidenced in the site analytics as well:

Only putting this on the "Top answer" feels even worse to me, it feels like you are promoting that specific answer; the top upvoted answer is NOT always the best answer. Pile on votes for old, bad answers, are a problem enough, and a lack of downvotes on those answers is a problem as well; don't make the problem worse by suggesting people add more pile on upvotes to the "top" answer when it could be far from the best. The pop-up should be post agnostic, and vote type agnostic as well, in my opinion.
If you won't implement this, will you be able to determine after the prompt how many people voted on an answer different to the one they were prompted to, and/or if they downvoted (on the answer you suggested to upvote)?

Further in regards to Downvotes, and the lack of them, I wrote a "quick" SEDE to see the weight of use of downvotes to upvotes. I included only uses that are (currently) about to cast both up and down votes, and have voted at least 100 times. I was not expecting the sheer volume of people that have never cast a downvote but cast 100 upvotes; 39432 users (averaging over 300 votes each). There are more users that have used 100% of their votes for upvotes that users who have less <90% of their votes for upvotes.
These users could be making a lot of upvotes, however, rarely (never) downvote, and this is really important. I therefore really suggest that Stack Overflow reconsider weighing on Upvotes alone; ask people to vote that's all you need to do. How they vote, up or down, is less important; we need people to be using their votes correctly, and just upvoting doesn't do that.
Result of the SEDE:



PercUpvotes
Upvotes
Downvotes
Users




0-5%
61781
2673803
192


5-10%
155354
1920975
236


10-15%
220985
1561099
329


15-20%
276311
1330406
345


20-25%
357896
1234255
389


25-30%
264448
697489
469


30-35%
391906
809915
568


35-40%
435051
721954
739


40-45%
533700
725159
864


45-50%
656790
726249
956


50-55%
707456
638538
1201


55-60%
965810
718012
1596


60-65%
1212631
725597
2021


65-70%
1404695
671552
2487


70-75%
2142606
808445
3655


75-80%
2753700
795992
5130


80-85%
4070497
855411
8326


85-90%
7137658
997852
15067


90-95%
15720447
1210095
33970


95-100%
98634067
1393352
155078


100%
12783331
0
39432



And visually if you are so inclined


Not to discount any of your points, but one logical reason to put it on the top answer is that's the first one a user will see when scrolling, so it's more likely that a user will see it.  Though if it makes voting patterns worse in the way you fear, it may still be worse to put it there, even so.

I'd rather it just be detached from posts entirely, @M.Justin . He could be a banner, or a "floating" bubble. It shouldn't be attached to the first answer.

I just want to highlight here that we penalize people for downvoting. I'm not arguing that this is an important part of curation, but we do penalize people for this curation. Collectively, if we feel that this is important, then we should incentivize this behavior or at the very least, not penalize it. Perhaps if an item is downvoted by a gold tag or two silver tags or closed then points could be refunded for all curators (or some such thing)

Yeah, I really dislike that downvoting answers "costs" reputation, @JonSG . There's a question where I think I have about downvoted 9 or more answers, because they are all open to SQL injection attacks. It, however, costs me reputation to tell others than the solution is not only not good, but bad because it's has a massive security vulnerability. Don't get me wrong, i'd do it again, but it's silly that experience users have to "pay" to tell others that answers are bad.

"Only putting this on the "Top answer" feels even worse to me, it feels like you are promoting that specific answer; the top upvoted answer is NOT always the best answer." I fully agree. Moreover, this feeds into the widely spread misconception that many users attest to - that only the top answer matters. Many times I've pointed users to a duplicate with 10+ answers knowing fully well one of them works. However, they've come back to me and claimed "it" doesn't work. "it" being the top-most answer. While answer #2 or #3 fully addressed their issue.

I think I would qualify as one who upvotes a lot but rarely downvotes. I don't have much reputation and the penalty for downvoting is therefore much more significant for me than the people with a "k" after their reputation score.

And that's part of the problem, @MT1 ; people don't vote on answers because they they value internet points. Question downvotes don't "cost" anything though.

@MT1 Only about 13% of my votes are upvotes and I have way less rep than you

Change the text from "Did this work?" to "Is this useful?" in the new voting popover:

Not every answer is a matter of making something work. For example, understanding questions (as opposed to problem-solving questions). (Thanks to starball for pointing this out in comments.)
This is consistent with the current text on mouseover: "This answer is useful".
The question "Did this work?" suggests that the user should test the answer before voting.

Testing the answer is not necessary for the upvote. I often upvote answers from which I learn something potentially useful, without necessarily testing whether the answer actually works.
Saying "it is useful" instead of "it works" lowers the "psychological bar" to vote on an answer.
The converse is also true. For example, a duplicate answer (which is redundant, and contributes nothing new, given an already existing answer), may very well work, but it is not useful.




On the subject of "Did this work?", it would be great to do more experiments to encourage users to accept the answer that works best for them. There are so many answers for which the users said in comments that this answer solved their problem, but they did forgot (?) to accept this answer.

the rationale I'd give instead is that not every answer is a matter of making something work. Ex. understanding questions (as opposed to problem-solving questions).

This is my own personal voting philosophy, but one reason I don't always vote (or don't always vote right away) is that I don't want to upvote a good looking answer before making sure it actually works.  This is especially true when there are multiple answers with different approaches.  I feel the system is harmed more by bad upvotes than a reduced number of good upvotes.

Note: this answer post was first written before the clarification that downvotes will not be encouraged as part of this experiment, or at least this round of this experiment.

I support this. I'd love to see people make use of their voting privilege more (provided they're voting based on whether things are useful to them or not). I suspect that not voting is a habit formed from votes appearing to be meaningless before gaining privileges (and to a large extent, that's true).
Questions-

When they have downvote privileges, what will the popover look like? Will it only encourage them to vote up? Voting down is equally important.
What about questions? The example screenshot shows the popover for an answer post, but what about question posts?
What happens when there are multiple answer posts?
I like that the popover is close to the buttons themselves, but given the two questions above, was it considered to use the existing stuff like the "welcome back- remember to vote" and "you haven't voted on questions/answers in a while" things, which appear at the top of the page?


Update: Okay, I'm disappointed to hear that this will only encourage upvoting (and only on the top answer post) and not downvoting, considering that downvoting was mentioned explicitly in the question post :/

The experiment will focus on upvoting only; answers only; on the top answer only, if there are multiple. The pop-over will not show concurrently to the currently existing banners. We will see what we learn, and go from there.

@JNat there are more users who have the upvote privilege as this requires lower rep, and by your own numbers the fraction of people with the privilege who actually use it is about 3.3 times higher for upvotes than downvotes. This means if this site is lacking voting users, there is a significantly higher lack of downvoters than upvoters. There are also significant issues with lower and lower content quality, and garbage being upvoted or at least not downvoted is a big part of that. So why the hell does SE focus on upvotes again and again and ignores downvotes?

@JNat does top answer depend on the sorting rule? The top answer for a Trending sort might be different from a top answer for a Highest score sort, which might also be different from a Date created sort. In any case, I think this should be shown on all answers or none at all. Prompting users to vote on a specific answer doesn’t seem right. Or if it has to be a single answer, then choose that answer randomly.

If people feel strongly enough to have an opinion, they don't need to be reminded that voting exists; It's right there at the top of every post in the most prominent location on the page. We should instead be focusing on understanding why people aren't voting rather than using cheap gimmicks to annoy people into voting.
At best this feature would encourage a half dozen people 4 times a year to cast votes. There are far more obvious places we could look to find people who currently aren't voting but would be more than happy to.

the first and last sentence here seem to clash? unless the last sentence is talking about increasing access to full voting privileges.

@starball in a sense, it is, but i don't think full voting privileges earlier is the only way to accomplish it.
